# overlaySKSScene not working: SpriteKit scene does not appear in SCNView

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scenekit, skscene, scnnode

Answers to similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584257/how-can-i-overlay-a-skscene-over-a-scnscene-in-swift) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936540/overlay-skscene-is-not-showing) did not solve the problem.

Assigning a SpriteKit scene to the `overlaySKScene` property of a SCNView does nothing: the SpriteKit scene does not appear at all.

Tested on iPhone 7 and on the Simulator.

Running the code below shows a blank white screen.

```
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let skScene = SKScene(size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
    skScene.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "AddButton.png")
    skScene.addChild(node)

    sceneView.overlaySKScene = skScene
    sceneView.overlaySKScene!.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    sceneView.overlaySKScene?.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not there? `backgroundColor` doesn't seem to work on `overlaySKScene` and your node will be added in the corner. Can you see it if you position the node? e.g. `node.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2, y: self.view.frame.size.height/2)`

Comment: @JamesP tried positioning the node, but unfortunately it's not showing up. any other ideas? does the code above work for you?

Comment: It works for me on a default SceneKit project. Is the sceneView actually showing up?

Comment: @JamesP yes the sceneView shows up. hmmm, weird that it works for you.

Comment: We just created a blank project as well to test this, and it's still not working. No button appears. Are you doing anything else besides pasting the code above?

Comment: I can't see in your code where you're setting the SCNScene on the sceneView. That could stop the overlay showing.

Comment: @JamesP where do you set it? we have tried setting it before and after the `scene` property of the SCNView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me after setting up a default SceneKit project.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
  let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
  scnView.scene = scene

  let skScene = SKScene(size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
  let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "testImage.png")
  skScene.addChild(node)

  scnView.overlaySKScene = skScene
  scnView.overlaySKScene!.scaleMode = .resizeFill
}
```

The overlay view wouldn't show up unless the `SCNScene` was set on the view, and the background colour of the `SKScene` had no effect.